# Enter Data to main form

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, label

[image]I Made an application. The Main form Name is Form1.
And the other Form is called PoP.

```
public partial class pops : Form
{
    public pops()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CenterToScreen();
    }

    private void pops_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }

    private void lblAdminNo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice picture, but what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make two public properties on popup form and retrieve them from parent form.

```
string username = string.Empty;
string password = string.Empty;

using (LoginForm form = new LoginForm ())
 {
     DialogResult result = form.ShowDialog();
     if (result == DialogResult.Ok)
     {
         username = form.Username;
         password = form.Password;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on from where are you calling the Pop form.

If it is called from the Form1 itself, then the Popform's object itself would provide you the value.

```
Pop popFrm = new Pop();
if(popFrm.ShowDialog() == Ok)
{
   string userName = popFrm.TextBox1.Text;
}
```

If the Pop is invoked from a different area/part of application, you may have to store it somewhere common to both the forms.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done through events. This approach is particularly useful when data to be posted even when the child form is kept open.

The technique is- From parent form, subscribe to a child from event. Fire the event when child form closes, to send data

**----- SAMPLE CODE-----**

Note: In the Parent Form add a Button:*button1*

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{

 public delegate void PopSaveClickedHandler(String text);

 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
  public Form1()
  {
   InitializeComponent();
  }

  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
   Pops p = new Pops();
   p.PopSaveClicked += new PopSaveClickedHandler(p_PopSaveClicked);//Subscribe
   p.ShowDialog();
  }

  void p_PopSaveClicked(string text)
  {
   this.Text = text;//you have the value in parent form now, use it appropriately here.
  }
 }
```

Note: In the Pops Form add a TextBox:*txtUserName* and a Button:*btnSave*

```
 namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
 public partial class Pops : Form
 {

  public event PopSaveClickedHandler PopSaveClicked;
  public Pops()
  {

   InitializeComponent();
  }

  private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
  if(PopSaveClicked!=null)
  {
    this.PopSaveClicked(txtUserName.Text);
  }
  }
 }
}
```

**Summary:**

1.Add a delegate(place where it available to both parent and child form) :

```
 public delegate void PopSaveClickedHandler(String text);
```

2.In form:Pops, Add an event:

```
 public event PopSaveClickedHandler PopSaveClicked;
```

3.Subscribe to the event in Parent Form:

```
p.PopSaveClicked += new PopSaveClickedHandler(p_PopSaveClicked);
```

4.Invoke the event in  form:Pops Save Button Click

```
if(PopSaveClicked!=null)
{
  this.PopSaveClicked(txtUserName.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send data to the form object before you display it. Create a method to call, send the info through the constructor... etc.

Comment: You could create public properties in the Form1 object and set them before displaying Form1. Or you could add the arguments UserName Password to Form1's constructor. Then in Form1's constructor, set member variables in Form1 using that data.

Either way you'll need to add variables to Form1 to store the data, and set them somehow from POP.

Another option is to overload the method that displays Form1, and add the arguments there.